# Flutter responsive design when App supports only Mobile devices portrait mode(No web, tablet, desktop support)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, responsive, portrait

We are going to develop a mobile app using flutter. This app supports only mobile devices and only portrait mode.

How to make the app works on all mobile devices with less amount of effort.

I have read some tutorials about Layout Builder, Aspect Ratio, Orientation builder. But I feel they will be very much helpful when we are going to support multiple platforms like web, Desktop, Mobile landscape mode.

Since my app supports only portrait mode(Mobile). Do we have any tricks to make the app responsive in less amount of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not matter your app supports only portrait mode on Mobile. You still need a responsive design for different sized mobile phones. As you answered yourself, you can use the following properties of Flutter to get a highly responsive design:

- LayoutBuilder
- MediaQuery
- AspectRatio
- FittedBox
- FractionallySizedBox
- OrientationBuilder

In addition to all, you can look [here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/adding-responsiveness-to-your-flutter-widgets-c6a5da953b02) for more.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the responsive_builder package for this, or responsive_framework.
And use also widgets for responsiveness, for example Expanded, Flexible, LayoutBuilder, among others...